# Play RTSP H264 stream with MSE

Tags: javascript, h.264

I would like to play a h264 stream in html5 (mse) which comes from a live camera.

What I want to achieve is to push raw h264 frames over websocket, and leave the fragmentation on the browser itself.

It should wait for the pps/sps units then it should do the fragmentation for the mse playback.

The server (camera) which creates the stream, *can* run ffmpeg to fragment the h264 to mp4 but it is starting slow (takes too much time while finding sps/pps). This is why I want to do  the whole thing on the client-side.

I have tried [MP4Box.js](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/) without success. Now looking at [mux.js](https://github.com/videojs/mux.js/) but still unsure how can I do this.

(If I run ffmpeg and wait until it finds sps/pps, I can display the stream in the HTML5 video item with mse)

Technically, ffmpeg command line will contain '-analyzeduration 32' to prevent ffmpeg from keep my device hanging. (But this also prevents it to wait for the correct sps/pps units => that's why I will need to do it on the client side)

Comment: Doing it on the client will not speed things up. The SPS/PPS will not arrive any faster. It will just be the client waiting, instead of the server waiting.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for could you help me with this?

Comment: A client side "H.264 Annex B" to "fragmented MP4" reduces the latency and speeds up the start up. Because sever side solution requires the server to wait until the fragment is fully assembled before transmission. So with a client side fragmentation the startup time is reduced by the fragment transmission duration which can be significant.

Comment: Thanks Markus. Can you post an answer with a possible solution for client side annexb to fmp4?